# Blue-white or white and blue?

Tags: idiomatic-language

What is the most natural way to describe the color of an object as a combination of blue and white? For example we prefer "black and white" to "white and black". Does it matter which color is predominant?

Comment: No. Blue-white and white and blue are not comparable.

Blue-white describes a mixture of the two colours, evenly spread across however much canvass. White and blue is unclear but tends to suggest stripes, or perhaps white clouds against a blue sky. 

We prefer "black and white" for no obvious reason but it being "black on white" and that's a completely different Question.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean pale blue? Is it closer to white? Or closer to blue? Or do you mean 2 distinct colours?

Comment: @TomJNowell: No, I mean a combination of two distinct colours.

Comment: can you rephrase? a combination of 2 distinct colours could mean 2 different things. E.g. purple is a combination of 2 distinct colours ( red and blue ), or you could be referring to blue and red stripes. It is still ambiguous, an example/image would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's interesting to compare the usage of both orders in the Google Ngram Viewer. In almost all cases, white comes last:

[Black](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=white+and+black%2Cblack+and+white&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) (about five times as often):

[image]

[Blue](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=white+and+blue%2Cblue+and+white&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) (about two times as often):

[image]

The only exception I could find was [yellow](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=white+and+yellow%2Cyellow+and+white&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), where it's about equal:

[image]

Roughly, the order seems to be

**red** > **black** > **blue, green** > **yellow, white**

In general, the combination with *and* seems to be preferred over the hyphen:

[image]

([source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blue+and+white%2C+blue-white&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3))

Comment: I don’t think there is a “preference” for *and* over a hyphen—I think they refer to different things. “Blue and white” refers to something that has some blue and some white—stripes, a base color with a trim of another color, etc. “Blue-white” to me connotes a single color, perhaps the color of those LED headlights, or a blowtorch.

Comment: @KRyan: Or very hot stars, e.g. types O, B, & A. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification#Class_O

Comment: @jamesqf Yup, another good example—though technically, arguably, it’s the _same_ example, since a blowtorch gets to be blue-white for the same reason that stars do.

Comment: I feel like there's some interesting linguistics here, possibly phonetics-related? in terms of what order the words go in.

Comment: @KRyan: Yes, and I think it's a fairly unusual usage.  Most similar cases I can think of either have their own names (e.g. pink for 'red-white"), or are an "-ish" combination (e.g. greenish yelllow, reddish purple, &c).  Maybe it's because the blue-white of stars, cutting torches, and LEDs represents something physical, an object radiating with a peak in the high end of the visible spectrum, or beyond.

Answer (score 17):

Particularly for those of us who learned colors from [Crayola crayons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Crayola_crayon_colors), the hyphenated form usually represents a blend of the colors — *yellow-orange* is a single color, of a hue somewhere in between yellow and orange.

Different distinct colors used in combination are usually listed out, in contrast. The [Austrian flag](https://www.britannica.com/topic/flag-of-Austria) is red and white, the [FC Barcelona](https://www.fcbarcelona.com/en/club/news/1725105/fc-barcelona-officially-unveils-2021-jersey/featured) jersey is red and blue, [Delftware pottery](https://www.bbc.com/culture/article/20200623-delftware-porcelain-the-global-story-of-a-dutch-icon) blue and white.

There are several common irreversible binomials, notably *black and white* and *black and blue* (when referring to bruising). In some other cases, a particular order has become idiomatic. The colors of Princeton University are always *orange and black*, never *black and orange*. The American flag is *the red, white, and blue* and Team Australia *the green and gold*.

It is difficult to reduce the patten to any kind of rule for general use, however. In pairs, I think the more distinctive color naturally comes first, so the Greek flag would commonly be described as *blue and white*. On the other hand, the colors of my high school were always given as *black and gold*, because black was the primary color, and gold only used as an accent.

Ultimately, at least if providing a simple description, I do not think you need to be overly concerned about order. I do not think anyone would object to listing the colors of the Japanese flag as either *white and red* or *red and white*.

Comment: I don't think "silver and gold" is an irreversible binomial – I'd almost always say "gold and silver" instead, and [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gold+and+silver%2Csilver+and+gold&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) agrees with me.  "Silver and gold" feels like a very particular reference, although to what I can't say.  But "the emperor's clothes were gold and silver" is a perfectly normal sentence.  (Context: native AmE speaker from the northeast.)  But I must say, despite my one quibble there, this was a great answer!

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky I think you're right about it being a specific reference. In my head I'm hearing a song lyric or poem that goes "something and something and silver and gold", but I can't place where it comes from.

Comment: @Barmar:  [Silver and gold.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rY-XDQN6ipE)  From the "Rudolph the Red Node Reindeer" Christmas cartoon.

Comment: @JRE That's not the one I was thinking of. The one in my head is more upbeat and has "something and something" before the phrase.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky "silver and gold" is sometimes a reference to the different pay roles of the Panama Canal. Whites getting gold, Blacks silver. U2 did an anti-apartheid record with the title.

Comment: Fair enough, I've removed the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You won't notice the difference in spoken language, but another option is to separate colours with a slash, for example ["green/yellow"](https://cpc.farnell.com/search?st=green%20yellow%20sleeving) or ["black/white"](https://cpc.farnell.com/search?st=black%20white)
to denote those combination of colours. This is very common when describing objects in product listings or technical specifications, less so in more literary uses.